# Update via commandline unavailable

Tags: 14.04, command-line, updates

I attempted to update through the terminal, but it responded with errors I haven't encountered with before.

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

EDIT: I used

> sudo apt-get update

Comment: What command did you use on the terminal?  And under what user were you when you ran that command?

Comment: "is another process using it?" you have another application open that keeps occupied /var/lib/dpkg/. pls make sure you have closed tools such as synaptic, ubuntu update/software center etc. and then re-run the command